# flutter riverpod - family provider rebuilds when not neccesary

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I have a `StateNotifierProvider` called `taskListProvider`, which is connected to a class called `TaskList` (a `StateNotifier`), that holds a list of `Task`s

both `Task` and `TaskList` have ==() and hasCode() defined.

In the UI, I am presenting these tasks in 4 differnt lists, filtered by their `TaskRating`, which is an enum defined like this:

```
enum TaskRating { none, urgent, important, both }
```

To create the 4 lists, I created a Provider.family called `tasksByRatingProvider`:

```
final tasksByRatingProvider =
    Provider.autoDispose.family<List<Task>, TaskRating>((ref, rating) {
  final filteredTasks =
      ref.watch(taskListProvider).where((t) => t.rating == rating);
  final selectedCategory = ref.watch(categoryFilter);

  if (selectedCategory == null) return filteredTasks.toList();

  return filteredTasks
      .where((task) => task.categoryId == selectedCategory.id)
      .toList();
})
```

Each of these lists is inside a card Widget.

When I update one of the tasks, I expected that only the card holding the task to update, but it seems that all of the cards, even the ones that don't contain the task that was updated, are being rebuilt each time.
does anyone have an idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Riverpod has its own mechanism for filtering Providers to prevent unnecessary rebuilds: [`select`](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-select-to-filter-rebuilds)

Instead of `ref.watch(taskListProvider).where((t) => t.rating == rating)`, try `ref.watch(taskListProvider.select(t) => t.rating == rating))`.

Comment: Hey man - inside the select funtion I dont get a single task, but a List of Tasks, so the code you wrote doesn't actually work. the closest I can get is 'taskListProvider
      .select((tasks) => tasks.where((t) => t.rating == rating))' but that also doesn't work

Comment: Try converting your list into something using deep equality, like the EqualitySet from the collections package.